# Do While loop not looping all rows-exiting after the 15th count

Tags: vba, csv, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a VBA sub to open a folder containing 250 csv files.  Each of these files have 1400 rows.

I want to delete the rows (in the csv files) based on 2 arguments.

Every thing working fine, except the code exits the for loop after the counter `i` is 15

```
Sub Iterate_Files()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim Foldr As String, File As String, i As Integer _
  , Price As Range, Vol As Range, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
  Foldr = "D:\Workspace\Data\EOD_2yrs14&15 - Copy\"
  File = Dir(Foldr)      'Retrieving the first file            
Do While File <> ""  'Start the loop to iterate csv files.
  Workbooks.Open Foldr & File
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Foldr & File)
  Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) '
  Set Price = ws.[F1:F1400]
  Set Vol = ws.[G1:G1400]
    For i = 1 To Price.End(xlDown)  'to avoid overruning of loop
       If Price(i) = "" Then
       Exit For
       End If
      If Price(i) < 50 Then     '1st criteria to delete row
          Price(i).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
          i = i - 1
      ElseIf Vol(i) < 300000 Then '2nd criteria to delete row
          Price(i).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
          i = i - 1
      End If
    Next
Loop
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges = True
File = Dir()                 ' retrive the next csv file
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code has severe formatting problems.

Comment: Fix indentions and attach your first workbook, I will re consider my -1 vote

Comment: `Price(15)` wouldn't happen to `= ""` , does it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  For i = 1 To Price.End(xlDown)
```

is the same as

```
  For i = 1 To Price.Cells(1).End(xlDown).Value
```

since `Value` is the default property for a Range object. So your loop will end whenever `i` reaches whatever value is in the cell reached by `End(xlDown)`

Possibly you want:

```
  For i = 1 To Price.End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answere.I was somehow missing the point.Now it is working fine.Also "For i=1 To Price.rows.count" works.